# Bootstrap navigation collapse on large screen

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I have checked many sites using bootstrap menu, it collapse after certain screen size , I am using 22 inch screen and navbar collapse when I see my website..

Comment: change media query in css file of bootstrap as per your requirements

Comment: Thats what it is supposed to do, isn't?

Comment: navbar menu's supposed to collapse only when you are on smaller screen. If its collapsing in a 22 inch screen then there is something wrong with your screen resolution. Make sure you have set your classes correctly and if you could post your code it would help others ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use media query for your screen size in terms of pixels.

For example:

```
// Landscape phones and below
@media (max-width: 480px) { ... }

// Landscape phone to portrait tablet
@media (max-width: 768px) { ... }

// Portrait tablet to landscape and desktop
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 980px) { ... }

// Large desktop
@media (min-width: 1200px) { .. }
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap menu can be resized for almost many kind of screens like mobile, tablet, ipad, laptop, desktop etc. But some resolutions may have missed out in their media query. For ex: as you told " I am using 22 inch screen ".. your desktop's max-width may not have listed in their inbuilt  media query.

So, what I suggest is it is better to write your own media query for that types of cases.

For example,

```
@media (max-width: 1080px) { ... }
@media (max-width: 1440px) { ... }
```